# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@mui/base'

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, base-ui

I just installed Material UI, and found messages like this:

```
Compiled with problems:

ERROR in ./node_modules/@mui/material/AccordionActions/AccordionActions.js 7:0-70

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@mui/base' in 'C:\..\node_modules\@mui\material\AccordionActions'
```

By the way, I use yarn.
and at terminal i get

```
webpack compiled with 253 errors and 1 
warning
```

and this my package.json dependencies:

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.9.0",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.8.1",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.8.2",
    "@mui/material": "^5.8.2",
    "@mui/styled-engine-sc": "^5.8.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.3.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-router-dom": "5.3.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.5",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
```

I've used `yarn add @mui/base`, but it's still like that, is there a workaround?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

simply install the mui base first .
if you are using npm then go with this command :

```
npm install @mui/base
```

if you are using yarn then go with this command :

```
yarn add @mui/base
```

Answer (score 1):

check out this links:
first one is official material UI and second npm

1. https://mui.com/base/getting-started/installation/
2. https://www.npmjs.com/package/@mui/base

Comment: I'm confused to find a solution, I'm also confused, why does it get an error